# Converting String to double

Tags: java

I'm still a student and i started learning the java programming language newly,I just wanted to ask about how to convert an argument in the function main from a string to a double,just like converting a string to an integer with Integer.pasreInt(arg)

Comment: Given you know how to convert a `String` to an `int`, I might be worth expanding that knowledge by taking a punt and looking at the JavaDoc for `Double` - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html

Comment: Don't be scared to make mistakes, no harm in taking a shot in the dark and exchanging the types in that statement, pass a Double arg and crossing your fingers.

Answer (score 3):

`Double.valueOf(arg)` or `Double.parseDouble(arg)`

Comment: Should we answer to duplicate questions

Comment: Please mates, if it's a duplicate, and it sounds to be one, flag it instead of replying (even if you one is really good :)).

Comment: Probably not, in this case the answer was easier than finding the duplicates though :) Having said that he should have been able to find this easily himself so a nudge in that direction would be in order...

Comment: Remember to put try{}catch(NumberFormatException e){}